# Providing insight to another person

Tags: prepositions, word-usage, appropriate

Can I provide insight to another person? Ex: I provided my client insight to his problem.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: We generally speak of insight *into* something, not *to* it.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide insight to another person or provide another person with insight.

Your example should then be: I provided my client **with** insight into his problem.